# VB.net Class Not Registered Error

Tags: vb.net, shell32, clsid

I'm in the process of writing a VB application but whenever I run the application I get the error listed below:

"An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {11219420-1768-11D1-95BE-00609797EA4F} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))."

I have tried registering the shell32.dll file, I have looked in the registry for the entry {11219420-1768-11D1-95BE-00609797EA4F} but it does not exist, and I have tried compiling this application for x86.

```
Imports Shell32
Imports System.IO
Public Class frmIconChanger
    Dim sh As ShellLinkObject = New ShellLinkObject
    Private Sub btnBackupAndChange_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBackupAndChange.Click
        For Each desktopIcon In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("C:\Users\" + getUserName().ToString + "\Desktop")
            Dim fileExtension As String = Path.GetExtension(desktopIcon)
            If (fileExtension = ".lnk") Then
                MsgBox(sh.GetIconLocation(desktopIcon).ToString)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Function getUserName() As String
        Return System.Environment.UserName.Trim
    End Function
End Class
```

Other information:  I am on a Windows 7 64-bit machine.  I have .Net 4.0 and previous versions and am working in Visual Studio 2012.    Also I have shell32.dll added as a reference in my project. Any help resolving this issue would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this link [Creating Links](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11467/How-to-create-short-cuts-link-files). Take a look at the "C" code and look for constants
CLSID_ShellLink
IID_IShellLink

Those are the values you need for the class and interface.

This other link is useful: [IShellLink interface](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/74471-com-queryinterface/)

This should be the GUIDs you need:
    CLSID := "{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
    IID := "{000214F9-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"